# 1054, Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql, django, vagrant, vagrantfile

Real error: 1054, Unknown column 'group_shop_item.promo_discount' in 'field list'

I added a column on the Items table, ran makemigrations, then migrate. And now a 1054 error came up. Since I'm running it on a Vagrant Box, I ran vagrant up --provision and dropped & replaced mysql database. The column is still not showing on the database.

Any help on specifying the reason as to why there is a discrepancy in the migrations process would be greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    obj_manager = ItemManager()
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    promo_discount = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, 
    decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Are you sure the database is properly synced and migrated? Does the `django_migrations` table reflect your expectations?

Comment: @Charlie django_migrations reflect the table change, and ran synchronization of database; however, none of that work. I'm assuming it's my own system but as per Briggs Mcknight's recommendation below, I was able to make it work.

Comment: also make sure you connected to the right database that contains that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the column manually in mySQL and see if that works.

Comment: This actually works temporarily, and I have been using this every time; however, I wonder if there is a permanent fix to this?

Comment: This might get the app working but I agree that it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: CoderBriggs is correct, but here is a bit more information as to [why](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#s-mysql) . When the column isn't created after a migration fail, which happened to me, you would have to create a column manually either through database commands.